# how to add auto increment and primary key in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlite

how to add auto increment and primary key using c# ?

im use sql server 2008 and sqlite

here is my code

use sqlite

```
Dictionary<String, String> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            field.Add("id", "INT");
            field.Add("mac", "VARCHAR(25)");
            field.Add("serial_number", "VARCHAR(25)");
            cDatabaseSQLite.CreateTables("satuan", field);
```

use sql server

```
Dictionary<String, String> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            field.Add("id", "INT");
            field.Add("mac", "VARCHAR(25)");
            field.Add("serial_number", "VARCHAR(25)");
            cDatabaseSQLServer.CreateTables("satuan", field);
```

EDIT

```
public int CreateTables(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            switch (sqlType)
            {
                case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_SQLITE:
                    return cSQLite.CreateTables(tableName, data);
                case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_MSSQL:
                    return cSQL.CreateTables(tableName, data);
            }
            return 0;
        }


public int CreateTables(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            string s = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (";
            bool first = true;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = s + ",";
                }
                string s1;
                s1 = String.Format("{0} {1}", val.Key, val.Value);
                s = s + s1;
            }
            s = s + ")";
            return this.ExecuteNonQuery(s);
        }
```

Comment: Where does this `CreateTables` method come from? It's not a standard method in the framework, so far as I'm aware, and the details of how it works are probably necessary to know *if* it supports auto-increment or primary key features.

Comment: see edit in my question. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server check this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp and for SQLite, this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm

So, i think your code must look like this

for SQLite

```
Dictionary<String, String> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            field.Add("id", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");
            field.Add("mac", "VARCHAR(25)");
            field.Add("serial_number", "VARCHAR(25)");
            cDatabaseSQLite.CreateTables("satuan", field);
```

and this for SQL Server

```
Dictionary<String, String> field = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            field.Add("id", "INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY");
            field.Add("mac", "VARCHAR(25)");
            field.Add("serial_number", "VARCHAR(25)");
            cDatabaseSQLServer.CreateTables("satuan", field);
```

Comment: I would suggest to add comma after every data type except for the last one so that the method createtables would be definitely shorter and less logic to worry.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server the keyword is PRIMARY KEY and IDENTITY and for sql lite it is PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.